# Avoid double calculations in SELECT and WHERE clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Let's assume I have a table called myTable with two columns : id and value. I also have a function called someFunction which calculates something based on myTable's id. Now, if I want to select records whose function's result is less than 100, and also display the function's result, how can I do that?

This query looks ok but does not it do calculation of the same thing twice - in WHERE clause and then in SELECT clause?

```
   SELECT dbo.someFunction(mt.id, date), mt.id
   FROM myTable mt
   WHERE dbo.someFunction(mt.id, date) < 100
```

Is there a way to re-write it to something like this pseudo-code:

```
   SELECT 'RESULT', mt.id
   FROM myTable mt
   WHERE dbo.someFunction(mt.id, date) < 100 as 'RESULT'
```

Comment: Rewrite `someFunction` as an inline table-valued function and you will not only be able to evaluate it just once, but avoid the general performance drop associated with scalar functions to boot. The latter is typically far more of a problem than any repeated evaluation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `apply`:

```
SELECT v.funval, mt.id
FROM myTable mt CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (dbo.someFunction(mt.id, date)) v(funcval)
WHERE funcval < 100;
```

SQL Server should evaluate this only once.

Comment: do you see ant benefit of using VALUES here instead of simple derived table such as SELECT dbo.someFunction... as funcval?

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev . . . There is no need for nesting.  A subquery should have the same behavior.  A CTE gets complicated, because it is evaluated every time it is referenced.

Comment: You are nesting VALUES clause anyway. I've tried to write the same query and it even got a bit shorter (2 characters!!! :) )
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c8abd/1
All 3 queries gave me the same plan. BTW with CTE, I do not get why people love that so much ...

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev . . . For a single result you can argue that it is "nesting".  When you are doing multiple interdependent calculations, that is not the case.

Comment: For anyone looking at in modern times, this CROSS APPLY query does not work because it is not a valid T-SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using the function twice in your query will result in function being called twice, you can simply use a sub-query to avoid function being called twice, something like this...

```
SELECT mt.*
FROM (
        SELECT dbo.someFunction(id, date) AS RESULT, id
        FROM myTable
    ) mt
WHERE mt.RESULT < 100
```